# Set windows geo location programmatically

Tags: c#, geolocation, gps, location

I use a specific GPS receiver which consumes the data and knows the current position. Windows does not recognize it (and also should not do this as I need the data for logging, ...).
Now I would like to set the current location of the system (I use VB.NET, but any hint how to do this would be welcome). Getting the location is easy with the System.Device.Location namespace, but setting the location I can find no example.

Thx and best regards Martin.

Update:
I found https://www.gpssensordrivers.com/ which accepts a TCP/IP data source for GPS data. My software could access the GPS via its COM port, process the data and forward it via TCP/IP to the GPSDirect app from the link which then provides it to windows. Cost 15$, but if it uses a user-mode driver it will be worth the money I think …

Comment: GPS receiver will show you the location which it receive and detect. Are you presenting the data on a map. I guess you are getting Lat and Long from GPS. When setting the location, you must provide your own coordinates.

Comment: Sure, but I want the coordinates be available as global location info in Windows that e.g. the Microsoft Map App displays it …

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for GPS NMEA data available via TCP/IP.

two pieces of software are able to do this:

- with the HW Virtual Serial Port VSP3 the TCP/IT can be mapped to a virtual serial port.
- the PilaBlu GNSS Location Geolocation Driver can read from this virtual com port and set the windows geolocation.

Opening a browser with google maps shows my current location

Comment: The HW Virtual Serial Port is not free-of-charge right?
I am in contact with the PilaBlu developer, there is also an option to direct read from TCP/IP in this software, not yet finished and still not enabled but in the pipeline. This would be the easiers solution I think. Regards Martin